# Highlight column based on date in 2 cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, calendar, conditional-formatting

I managed to get a column formatted based on the day value that I save in a certain cell.
How can I additionally check if the day is in the month current month which is represented by the merged cells in the picture below?

In example, currently the formula

> D$3:AB$3=DAY(TODAY())

would highlight 2 columns if the day value is 16/17 but I would like to only highlight the 16th October column in October.

Many thanks for your help

[image: Project Calendar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite understand your question, but in general I like to use full dates in a cell and format them to a day view.  This way you can always call up day, month or year from that same cell.

1. Use full dates in second row "26/10/2017".
2. Format second row to "dd" or "d".
3. Base all your conditional formatting on the second row.

If other cells in your calendar depend on row two:

instead of:

```
E$2
```

you use:

```
day(E$2)
```